# confine heading in tikz node using titleformat

Tags: tikz-pgf, chapters, titlesec

I'm using a quite fancy style for my chapter heading, i.e.

```
\documentclass[12pt,open=left]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage{scrpage2}\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{}}

\titleformat{\chapter}
[hang]
{}
{}
{0em}
{\Large \bf
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
      \node[text width=2.55cm] (chapter) at (0,0) {Ch \thechapter \newline \newline}; 
      \draw [ultra thick] (chapter.north east) -- (chapter.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}\hspace{0.5cm}
  \fi
\Huge}
[\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 
  \normalsize \vspace{-1.3cm} \hspace{2.85cm} 
  \tikz{
    \node[text width=10cm] (toc) at (0,0){
      \newline \newline \newline
      %\parindent=20em
      \begin{minipage}{12cm}
      %\parindent=20em
      \printcontents[c]{}{1}{}
      \end{minipage}
    }; 
    \draw [ultra thick] (toc.north west) -- (toc.south west);} 
\fi]


\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

\startcontents[c]
\chapter{Short chapter title}
\section{thats an arbitrary section}
\subsection{thats an arbitrary section}
\subsection{thats an arbitrary section}
\section{thats an arbitrary section}
\section{thats an arbitrary section}
\stopcontents[c]

\startcontents[c]
\chapter{Here appears a very long chapter title causing issues}
\section{thats an arbitrary section}
\subsection{thats an arbitrary section}
\subsection{thats an arbitrary section}
\section{thats an arbitrary section}
\section{thats an arbitrary section}
\stopcontents[c]

\end{document}
```

Unfortunatley, if the heading extends over 2 lines my style is corrupted. I'd like that the second line of the heading starts at the same position as the first line and the black line has no gaps.

The easiest solution seems to confine the heading in a tikz node with on side colored in black, but I couldn't find a working solution so far.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `explicit` package option, that lets you specify where the text will be printed.

When the option is enabled you can have something like:

```
\node [right,text width=12cm] at(chapter.south east){#1};
```

Into your `tikzpicture`, where `#1` sets the text position.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,open=left]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage{scrpage2}\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{}}

\titleformat{\chapter}
[hang]
{}
{}
{0em}
{\Large \bf
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[text width=2.55cm] (chapter) at (0,0) {Ch \thechapter \newline \newline};
      \draw [ultra thick] (chapter.north east) -- (chapter.south east);
      \node [right,text width=12cm] at(chapter.south east){#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}\hspace{0.5cm}
  \fi
\Huge}
[\ifnum\value{chapter}>0
  \normalsize \vspace{-1.3cm} \hspace{2.85cm}
  \tikz{
    \node[text width=10cm] (toc) at (0,0){
      \newline \newline \newline
      %\parindent=20em
      \begin{minipage}{12cm}
      %\parindent=20em
      \printcontents[c]{}{1}{}
      \end{minipage}
    };
    \draw [ultra thick] (toc.north west) -- (toc.south west);}
\fi]


\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

\startcontents[c]
\chapter{Short chapter title}
\section{thats an arbitrary section}
\subsection{thats an arbitrary section}
\subsection{thats an arbitrary section}
\section{thats an arbitrary section}
\section{thats an arbitrary section}
\stopcontents[c]

\startcontents[c]
\chapter{Here appears a very long chapter title causing issues}
\section{thats an arbitrary section}
\subsection{thats an arbitrary section}
\subsection{thats an arbitrary section}
\section{thats an arbitrary section}
\section{thats an arbitrary section}
\stopcontents[c]

\end{document}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

You can tweak the text style via the new node options.

Comment: @Mandy You're welcome :) Now that you have complete control over the text, I would consider using TikZ options for all the customization, removing those `\newline`s to gain vertical space etc. The result will be the same but the code will maybe look prettier and more easily controlled.